# Please write a regex to match this IP so I can filter out of google analytics

Tags: regex, google-analytics, ip

Through our proxy we end up exiting to the Internet as a variation of this IP. I need to write a reg-ex to filter this out of our Google Analyitics account so the visits from internal visitors are not included in our web analytics.

How can I match this ip range? The last quadrant of the IP is a wildcard as this could be any range.

95.172.74.*

Answer (score 0):

`95\.172\.74\.\d+`

See regex101: http://regex101.com/r/yR3gI1/1

Comment: Invalid IPs such as 95.172.74.05 would match the regex.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this one:

```
^95\.172\.74\.([1-9][0-9]?|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-5][0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])$
```

http://regex101.com/r/oI5oQ1/1

Comment: It matches `95.172.74.999`

Comment: Not yet really correct, it matches, for the last part, `725` but not `168`

Answer (score 0):

This will do the job:

```
^95\.172\.74\.(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be accurate you should use this:

```
^95\.172\.74\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$
```

This will match as well possible leading 0 as for example: 
95.172.74.1 
95.172.74.01 
95.172.74.001

But it will not match:

<strike>95.172.74.0001</strike>
<strike>95.172.74.256</strike>

Answer (score -3):

You could use below regex to validate any ip :

**regexp**   "([0-9]{1,3}).([0-9]{1,3}).([0-9]{1,3}).([0-9]{1,3})"

Comment: Apart your regex matches `999.888.777.123`, have you read the question?